# Winter Bash 2018 で編み物(お絵かき)を

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

今年(2018)のWinter Bashは、[メインサイト](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)で編み物をモチーフとした**お絵かき**ができるようです。
面白い作品があれば、ぜひこの質問への回答でシェアしてみてください。

参考：
[Winter Bash 2018 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319846/403540) - Stack Exchange Meta

Answer (score 4):

私のアイコンです。元々小学生の頃に Windows XP の MS Paint で描いたものでした。年月が経ち大人になったので、きっともっと上手く描けるでしょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

P.S. 無理でした。

Answer (score 3):

初めての帽子を獲得したので
記念すべきと
編んで（描いて）みました。

編み物が得意なので
きっとうまくできるでしょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

P.S. 無理でした。