# Winter Bash 2019 で編み物(お絵かき)を

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

今年(2019)も引き続き[メインサイト](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/)で編み物をモチーフとした**お絵かき**ができます。
面白い作品があれば、ぜひこの質問への回答欄にシェアしてみてください

参考：
[Winter Bash 2019 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339896/314875) - Stack Exchange Meta

[Winter Bash 2018 で編み物(お絵かき)を](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2884/14055) - スタック・オーバーフロー

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: カープ坊やを編みました]

カープ優勝祈願！